# redux thunk namespacing action and reducer on states

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

say I have login and signup, I should have 2 sets of states like

sign up

```
sign_up_request // to show loader
sign_up_success // to set response
sign_up_fail // to show error
```

login

```
login_request // to show loader
login_success // to set response
login_fail // to show error
```

This is still fine for one auth combined reducer, it won't be so big, but in some case it can grow really big coz one http call at least it has 3 actions and states, how to avoid duplication?

Answer (score 0):

to address your concern about when it grows big, what you can do is, create a separate helper function that serves this kind of specific actions or another option is to create a code generator(separate reducers and actions). i would prefer helper function over code generators.

visit: [simplify redux action request](https://medium.com/skyshidigital/simplify-redux-request-success-failure-pattern-ce77340eae06), you might get better idea.